# Getting a random object from an array, then remove it from array. iphone

Tags: iphone, arrays, object, random, sdk

I am having a problem with arrays, I want an object to be picked randomly from the array,
and then remove it and remove other objects that are specified in the "if" statement.

What I did..

in the .h

```
NSMutableArray *squares;
int s;
NSString *randomN;
```

Next, in the .m

Create a new array:

```
-(void) array{
    squares = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
}
```

and then choose a random object, if properties of the "if" met, remove the object from the array, do the while loop again.

```
-(void) start{

    s=5;

    while (s > 0){
     //I even tried it without the next line..
     randomN = nil;

     //Also tried the next line without ' % [squares count'
     randomN = [squares objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [squares count]];

     if (randomN == @"a"){
         [squares removeObject: @"a"];
         [squares removeObject: @"b"];
        s = s - 1;
        }

     if (randomN == @"b"){
         [squares removeObject: @"b"];
         [squares removeObject: @"c"];
        s = s - 1;
        }

     if (randomN == @"c"){
         [squares removeObject: @"c"];
        s = s - 1;
        }

     else {
     s=0;
     }
}
}
```

When I run the app, the app stops and quits as soon as the loop starts.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their are a few issues that are probably tripping you up:

You're initializing an already allocated array with a convenience constructor, you should pick one of the `alloc`/`init` pair or the convenience constructor by itself:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:...]
```

or:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:...]
```

Your remove lines are attempting to remove string *literals*. While your array contains string *instances* that contain the same *values* as the strings you're trying to remove, they're not the same exact instances of the string. You need to use `[stringVar isEqualToString:otherStringVar]` to compare the values instead of their references:

```
if ([randomN isEqualToString:@"a"])
```

instead of:

```
if (randomN == @"a")
```

Also, your `else` statement will fire **every time** for similar reasons as the second problem. Even if you use the correct string comparisons, your logic is probably off if you're trying to only execute one of those 4 blocks of code. To accomplish that, each of the `if`s after the first needs an `else`, like so:

```
if (/* test 1 */) {
}
else if (/* test 2 */) {
}
else if (/* test 3 */) {
}
else {
    // chained else's make only one block able to execute
}
```

instead of:

```
if (/* test 1 */) {
}
if (/* test 2 */) {
}
if (/* test 3 */) {
}
else {
    // this else only applies to the LAST if!
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers,, I did every thing you told me, and now it is working :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you should be using `initWithObjects` when creating the array (rather than `arrayWithObjects`).

You should always use an `init*` method after using `alloc` to create a new object.
The `arrayWith*` methods are 'convenience constructors' that `autorelease` the returned object.  By the time you come to using it, the array has probably been freed.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers,, I did every thing you told me, and now it is working :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

In objective-c, you can't compare strings using `==`, you have to use the `isEqual:` method. The `@"string"` notation produces a pointer to a string defined elsewhere in memory, and these can be different, even though the data they point to is the same.

So, instead of

```
if (randomN == @"a"){
```

try

```
if ([randomN isEqual:@"a"]){
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers,, I did every thing you told me, and now it is working :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As Alex said,

```
squares = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
```

This line should be

```
squares = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
```

or

```
squares = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", nil] retain];
```

Also,

```
randomN = [squares objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [squares count]];
```

If squares is empty, EXC_ARITHMETIC exception (Division by Zero) occurs on this line.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers,, I did every thing you told me, and now it is working :) Thank you very much